# Where are those defaults stored in OS X?

Tags: macos

I adjust my font aliasing setting by:

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 3
```

which is a hint from [macworld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090828224632809).

I am wondering where are these `defaults` stored and how can I retrive the current values? Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "global domain" preferences are stored in

`/Users/yourname/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.$UUID.plist`, where `$UUID` is, well, a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), identifying your machine.

Comment: Got it! I can see what are saved by: `open .GlobalPreferences.<UDID>.plist` in the `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/` folder.

Answer (score 2):

All preference files are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/ in .plist files named by reverse domain name, so for example com.Apple.iPhoto.plist or similar.  The 'defaults' command is just a front-end for that.

Comment: I tried to search the ` ~/Library/Preferences/` folder but cannot found any `AppleFontSmoothing` string. For this particular example, which plist file is storing the `3` value?

Comment: True, in general, but not in this case.

Comment: Ah, I see - it's in a subfolder as an invisible file.  So I would have been correct If I had said they're in ~/Library/Preferences/* and left it at that.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You wrote a global value that wasn't there before.

to read it now:

```
defaults -currentHost read -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing
```

to change it

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int SIZE#
```

to set it back to normal

```
defaults -currentHost delete -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing
```

Further down in the post you referenced this is all referenced.  More info on defaults can be found at apple's developer site.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html